# Apache caches a path somewhere, requests a script in a former document root

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

The setup details:

I have Apache 2.2.14 that runs under ubuntu 10.04. The document root directory for a virtualhost is set up as a symlink.

The requested script in a glance looks like:

```
<?php

// other useful stuff here
echo 'v1.2.42';
```

So apart from doing useful job the script outputs its version in the footer. The version is hardcoded in the script and is modified by a build script.

When the new version is deployed the document root is switched to a new version using pretty standard approach:

```
ln -s /path/to/app-1.2.43 app-new
mv -Tf app-new app # where `app` is the document root
```

After that I don't do any `reload` or `restart` for apache.

Today right after another release that's what I've experienced:

1. I upgraded `1.2.42` version to `1.2.43`
2. Opened the application in the browser
3. It was `42` in the bottom
4. `F5` - still `42`.
5. Then `42` and `43` appeared randomly. And after about 30 seconds the expected `43` started showing consistently.

Another server that has the similar configuration behaves exactly the same. And seems like there is some constant timeout until it starts working fine :-S

More configuration details:

apache is configured to run via mpm-prefork. php's version is 5.3.2 and it's installed as `mod_php`. There is **NO** any opcode cache installed.

Any ideas on where it could cache it? Would `apache2 reload` **guarantee** this won't happen?

PS: I've proven (to myself) that `apache reload` doesn't reset that state and the undefined behaviour continues.

**UPDATE**:

I've found that every apache worker expands the symlink to a document root into a real path.

And when you perform a graceful `reload` command - only spare workers are restarted, while the busy ones, including the ones who are serving Keep-Alive connections are kept until they are spare from work. I could reproduce it using 1 worker and it perfectly explains my observations.

Now the question is: how to interrupt keepalive connections gracefully?

Interesting article to read on topic: https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/apache_s_graceful_restart_reprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found a solution that suites me. It is a tiny script that does the following:

1. Turn off `KeepAlive` in apache config
2. Get current workers PIDs
3. Run `apache reload`
4. Wait for all workers from #2 to quit
5. Switch symlink
6. Turn on `KeepAlive` back and reload apache once again

Answer (score 1):

It definitely seems as though the apache process is caching the result of the symlink. Even an apache reload may not solve your issue, because a reload simply re-reads the config file and re-applies the new settings. It doesn't actually terminate the running processes.

I'm thinking the best way to handle the situation is an `apache2 restart`. This is probably safer than you may be thinking, because it will block new connections, and allow old connections to complete cleanly before restarting. On a moderate web server this should happen in under one second. And since HTTP is stateless, your users won't even notice. Other than a possible half second hang if they attempt to initiate a new connection during the restart.

Another possibility is to actually change the document root in your config and the name of your symlink, then do an `apache2 reload`. It should then detect the new document root and force a re-resolution of the symlink's referenced directory.

The last thing I can think of is to experiment with hard links. This will require a different workflow though to prevent over-writing your new app version.

Comment: "This is probably safer than you may be thinking, because it will block new connections, and allow old connections to complete cleanly before restarting" -- just tried it - it interrupts all current requests.

Comment: My apologies, I must have been recalling how some other daemon operates. Good to know anyway. Does your web app do long polling or something? I'm trying to understand why your keep-alive connections last so long as I believe apache's default keep-alive is 2 seconds.

Comment: Man I'm 0 for 2... you can't hard link a directory... Perhaps you can do something like `mount --bind app-1.2.3 app`. Then have a simple shell script that would quickly unmount and remount to a new app version. This would allow the directory to never be *resolved* in a sense, so you may never have to do an `apache reload`. I'm unsure whether this could make a worse interruption, but maybe worth an experiment.

Comment: Actually I've found a solution that suits me and allows to serve content seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Apache caches symlinks (`lstat` system call) in path components when `Options FollowSymlinks` is set (by design).

To avoid caching you can try `Option SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` that guarantees to not cache `lstat` call.

However that needs to be properly configured and performance impact needs to be measured. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html#symlinks)

Comment: Can you link to something that says Apache/httpd caches lstat calls please?